# Javascript regex: how matches can share the same keyword?

Tags: javascript, regex

[In this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pgschr/8ou4abza/1/) I have a regex that extracts tables from SQL select statements. The regex is run on two SQL statements and they should return the same matches: `["table1 t1, table2 t2", "table3 t3"]`.

The first SQL works fine (see console.log) the second one is not working (doesn't detect `table3 t3` apparently because the `join` keyword is both the last keyword in the previous match, and the first keyword of the second match.

Is there a way to tell regex to "go back" when trying to match?

Javascript:

```
var sql = "select * from table1 t1, table2 t2 where t1.col in (select col from table3 t3)";

var myRegexp = /(:?from|join)\s(.*?)(:?\s+where|\s+on|\s+inner|\s+outer|\s+full|\s+left|\s+right|\s+join|\s*\))/gi;

console.log(getMatches(sql,myRegexp,2));

sql = "SELECT column FROM table1 t1, table2 t2 join table3 t3 on t1.column_name=t3.column_name";

console.log(getMatches(sql,myRegexp,2));

function getMatches(string, regex, index) {
    var matches = [];
    var match;
    while (match = regex.exec(string)) {
        matches.push(match[index]);
    }
    return matches;
}
```

Comment: you have non-capturing group reversed `:?`, anyway, are you certain it is a good idea to parse sql with a regex?

Comment: I don't want to parse the entire sql, just to get table names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work if you don’t mind comma-separated tables being a single match:

```
/(?:from|join)\s+(.*?)(?:\)|\s+(?=where|on|inner|outer|full|left|right|join))/gi
```

For example, it gives `"table1 t1, table2 t2","table3 t3"` for the example in your question (quotes added around matches). [Live sample](http://jsfiddle.net/h5rx8tao/).

PS. As @GUIDO says, `(?: )` is the non-capturing group syntax, so you’ll need to change your function calls to `getMatches(sql,myRegexp,1)` w/ this regex.

Answer (score 1):

Guess I must preface this with the obligitory "Is this such a good idea?" Typically Regex is not the answer for things like this (e.g. parsing).

That said, I think this is what you're looking for.

There is what's known as [positive and negative lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) which instructs the regex engine to ensure the match is followed by something without that being part of the match

> Positive lookahead works just the same. `q(?=u)` matches a q that is
>   followed by a `u`, without making the u part of the match. The positive
>   lookahead construct is a pair of parentheses, with the opening
>   parenthesis followed by a question mark and an equals sign.

There are also matching positive/negative lookbehind, but I don't believe JavaScript supports it.

Answer (score 1):

This regex should give more accurate results:

```
/(?:from|join|,)\s(.*?)(?=\s+where|\s+on|\s+inner|\s+outer|\s+full|\s+left|\s+right|\s+join|\s*,|\s*\))/
```

regex:  https://regex101.com/r/lE0rD9/1
fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9m0cyLz2/

Comment: Adding the comma to that first non-capturing group does let table names be matched individually, but is unsafe for some queries. For example, running this regexp against `select name as handle, address as crib from table1 t1` gives `address as crib from table1 t1`.